# Which motherboard should I choose?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, memory, pc, 3d-display

I want to build a custom pc that can support i9-13900K and RTX 4090 in future as I'm a 3D artist, and a stock trader.

But for now I want a pc for stock trading, which can support i5, and 32GB/64GB RAM.

Can you recommend a motherboard that would allow me to easily switch from the i5 13th gen to the i9 13th gen, so that I just have to change the Processor from i5 13th gen to i9 13th gen in future, while also supporting the RTX 4090 and up to 128GB of 5200MHz RAM?

I have tried searching and reading about different versions of motherboard that supports i9, but I don't know how do I search something that can match my demands as a future proof pc. Currently I am on a budget, and I don't want to build a pc from scratch for my 3D works. Tbh I don't have much knowledge about these LGA thing, and cores. So, I asking for your help. Please suggest me something, and also explain how do I check if the suggested motherboard/specification is a good to go for me.

EDIT: I don't know much about PCI or IO slots. Currently I am on a low budget I can build a pc with i5 and 32GB RAM, but after 1 year or 2, I don't want to reinvest in building the whole pc. So what I actually want is to spend more today on any motherboard that can support i5 13th gen, and i9 13th gen after a year, RTX 4090, and 128GB RAM.
I have few recommendations for the same,
here are some:

1. MSI MAG Z790 TOMAHAWK WIFI
2. ASUS PRIME Z790-A WIFI
3. ASUS ROG Maximus XIII Hero (LGA 1200)
4. MSI MEG Z690 ACE (LGA 1700)
5. Gigabyte Z690 AORUS Xtreme (LGA 1700)

Please suggest me the best, if you understand my query.
Thank you.

Comment: The 13th gen i5 and i9 CPUs use the same socket, so any board that supports the i9 will definitely support the i5. This is a hard question to answer because you have asked something very broad. Could you revise the question to explain more about what you need from the PC overall to help us recommend a specific motherboard? Right now we could recommend anything with an LGA-1700 socket but it might not be what you really need.

Comment: Some questions that would help us recommend something if you answered them in an edit: What size of motherboard does the case fit? How many PCIe slots will you need for expansion cards? What kind of ports do you need on the rear IO? What kind of storage ports do you need on the board? Will the PC be in a hot room and need a motherboard that can handle high temperatures? Do you plan to overclock or use any other features that can lead to extra power consumption from the board?

Comment: Can you better define your needs here: "But for now I want a pc for stock trading". Stock trading is a broad activity and encompasses anything from Robinhood on your phone to running algos across a large compute grid. At its most normal you just need a browser. What are you trying to do here?